# System of equations that is true just for Golden ratio

Tags: systems-of-equations, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Consider the following equations
$$
\begin{array}{cccx}\tag{1}
z+1&=&\frac{1}{z}&,\\
z+2&=&\frac{1}{z^2}&,\\
\vdots &=& \vdots &,\\
z+k &=&\frac{1}{z^k}&.
\end{array}
$$
where $k$ is a positive integer number.

*Question:* How to find all positive real solutions of $(1)$ when $k$ is given.

*Example:* The only positive real solution of $(1)$ when $k=1$ and $k=2$ is the $z=\frac{1}{\mu}$, where $\mu=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$([Golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)).

*My try:* I prove that the system $(1)$ has no positive real solution for $k>2$.

*Proof:* Consider $(1)$ has a  positive real solution such as $z$, then we get 
$$
z+k=\frac{1}{z^k} \Longleftrightarrow  (z+k-1)+1=\frac{1}{z^k}  \Longleftrightarrow
 \frac{1}{z^{k-1}}+1=\frac{1}{z^k}
 \Longleftrightarrow  z^k+z-1=0
$$
but the equation $z^k+z-1=0$ has no positive real solution for $k>2$.

Is my proof correct.

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Edit(1):** My proof is incorrect since the equation $z^k+z-1=0$ has positive real solution for $k>2$. Is it possible to ask you to improve my proof or make a correct proof for the question. Thanks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Look at OPs proof at the bottom. Unless I'm misreading something here he/she does claim that $z^k+z-1=0$ has no positive real solutions for $k > 2$, which isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that $z^k+z-1=0$ has no positive solutions is false.  The left side is $-1$ at $z=0$ and $2$ at $z=1$ so the intermediate value theorem guarantees a solution in $(0,1)$

If you are trying to satisfy the whole system, a much easier approach is to show that $\frac 1\mu$ does not satisfy the third.  As you have shown it is the only solution for the first, there is no common solution.

Comment: Your discussion is correct. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect because it is based on a false promise. $z^k+z-1=0$ most definitely has positive real solutions for $k > 2$. It's hard to solve them exactly, but a plot will quickly show that it has positive real solutions.

Comment: You right. Do you have any idea about my question. Thank.